is there any way to combine below update statements
I am looking for best way to combine these 2 update statements or at least if first failes, is there a best way to report 2nd update as well failure instead of blindly running and completing of 2nd update statement:
code
update  empn.alloc1 P set  emailaddress = dbms_random.string('X', 20)||'@nodomain.com' where emailaddress is not null; 

commit;
update (select  p2.emailaddress email2,  p1.emailaddress email1 from empn.alloc2 P2,empn.alloc1 P1 where p2.id = p1.id) abc set  email2 = email1 ;

commit;
code

Not 100% sure what you are wanting so added two options below
Option 1
If either update statment fails it will rollback all updates that have been done logging the error out to dbms_output (this should be replaced with whatever logging system you use).
Begin
  udpate statment 1;
  update statment 2;
  commit;
exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('error niether update committed ' || sqlerrm );
  rollback;
end;

Option 2
If update statment 1 succeedes then it is commited, and it moves on to second update, if the second update fails the first is persisted but we log the error and rollback the second.
If  the first update  fails then it will log the error and raise to main exception where a rollback is done second update never runs.
as above the dbms_output should be replaced with whatever logging system you use
Begin
  begin
    udpate statment 1;
    commit;
  exception when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('update statment 1 failed ' || sqlerrm );  
    raise;
  end;
  
  begin 
     update statment 2;
     commit;
  exception when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('error update statment 1 commited, update statment 2 failed ' || sqlerrm );   
     raise;
  end;
exception when others then
  rollback;
end;


end; at the end is missing for 2nd option?, 2nd option is feasible for me.

You are correct I had missed an end, I have edited my answer and added the end;
